# Organizing methods in a file using drag&drop in the structure view

Tags: ruby, refactoring, rubymine

Coming from eclipse, I am used to be able to move methods around in a file by simply dragging them around in the structure view (called overvew in eclipse).

I have noticed that it is not possible in RubyMine by default. Is there a way to enable it?

If not, is there a feature request for this?

All I have found yet is this: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-2987, http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-9672 which considers only moving methods between classes,

Thank you

disclaimer: This started a copy of my [attempt to get an answer](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/450393?tstart=0) on the JetBrains forum.

Comment: should be migrated to superuser.com

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - I know I can move code blocks inside the editor. Cut and paste is less comfortable and fast than d&d. You usually consider yourself hardcore, when putting more effort in tasks then necessery?

Comment: @kostja: I personally think that having to reach for the mouse and use it is much more effort. But to each his own.

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-71

Comment: @LazyOne - thanks, voted. care to repost as an answer, so I can close the question?

Comment: @bicycle questions on how to use programming-related tools are on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: While referring to a tool primarily used for programming, this question is related to that tool's development and should go on the developers' forum.

Comment: @Iserni and it did go to the forum - I also say so in the question and provide the link. However after one week of waiting for an answer, I reposted it here and had an answer mere 3.5 hours later. So I disagree - even tool-related question have a much better chance of being answered on SO than on the tool's forum and this is what counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @LazyOne said in his comment, there is an open feature request for drag&drop inside the structure view : http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-71.

It has been created in Feb 2005 and is not scheduled for any upcoming version, with only 11 votes so far, so no need to get your hopes up.